# I cannot call my jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a jQuery function that adds and removes a class when clicking on a button.

The grey background will change depending on which button you click because I am adding and removing the `active-button` class each time.

```js
/* Add / remove the active button class */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('.sm-btn-right').click(function() {
    jQuery('.sm-btn-right').addClass('active-button');
    jQuery('.sm-btn-left').removeClass('active-button');
  });

  jQuery('.sm-btn-left').click(function() {
    jQuery('.sm-btn-left').addClass('active-button');
    jQuery('.sm-btn-right').removeClass('active-button');
  });

});
```

```css
.sm-btn-left {
  color: red;
}

.sm-btn-right {
  color: blue;
}

.active-button {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="server-location-button-wrap">
  <div class="sm-btn-left flag-map-btns map_btn active-button">
    Map
  </div>
  <div class="sm-btn-right flag-map-btns flags_btn">
    List
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I realised I needed similar functionality for some other buttons, so I decided to turn it into a reusable function that I could call when needed. But when I do that the function stops working, the `active-button` class does not change.

Here is my (broken) attempt at separating it out into it's own reusable function.

```js
/* Add / remove class */
function bgAddRemoveClass(elem1, elem2, theClassNoDot) {

  jQuery('elem1').click(function() {
    jQuery('elem1').addClass('theClassNoDot');
    jQuery('elem2').removeClass('theClassNoDot');
  });
  jQuery('elem2').click(function() {
    jQuery('elem2').addClass('theClassNoDot');
    jQuery('elem1').removeClass('theClassNoDot');
  });

}

/* Invoke the function */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  bgAddRemoveClass('.sm-btn-left', '.sm-btn-right', 'active-button');
});
```

```css
.sm-btn-left {
  color: red;
}

.sm-btn-right {
  color: blue;
}

.active-button {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="server-location-button-wrap">
  <div class="sm-btn-left flag-map-btns map_btn active-button">
    Map
  </div>
  <div class="sm-btn-right flag-map-btns flags_btn">
    List
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `jQuery('elem1')` is an array with zero results about finding an `<elem1>` tag in the currend page. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove quotes, you need variables not strings

```
jQuery(elem1).click(function() {
    jQuery(elem1).addClass(theClassNoDot);
    jQuery(elem2).removeClass(theClassNoDot);
  });
```

Comment: Doh! How did I miss that. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around `elem1`, `elem2` and `theClassNoDot` inside the `bgAddRemoveClass()` function. By adding quotes you are not using the values that are passed into the function and instead are passing `'elem1'` and `'elem2'` as values to jQuery.

```js
/* Add / remove class */
function bgAddRemoveClass(elem1, elem2, theClassNoDot) {

  jQuery(elem1).click(function() {
    jQuery(elem1).addClass(theClassNoDot);
    jQuery(elem2).removeClass(theClassNoDot);
  });
  jQuery(elem2).click(function() {
    jQuery(elem2).addClass(theClassNoDot);
    jQuery(elem1).removeClass(theClassNoDot);
  });

}

/* Invoke the function */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  bgAddRemoveClass('.sm-btn-left', '.sm-btn-right', 'active-button');
});
```

```css
.sm-btn-left {
  color: red;
}

.sm-btn-right {
  color: blue;
}

.active-button {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="server-location-button-wrap">
  <div class="sm-btn-left flag-map-btns map_btn active-button">
    Map
  </div>
  <div class="sm-btn-right flag-map-btns flags_btn">
    List
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean that you pass wrong parameters in add/remove Class function, use the name of inner parameter instead of using class name.
Try call the function like this way:

```
bgAddRemoveClass(elem1, elem2, 'someClass');
```

then:

```
jQuery(elem1).addClass(someClass);
jQuery(elem2).removeClass(someClass);
```