# I cannot selectively run my function on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a follow on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183115/i-cannot-call-my-jquery-function).

I have two sets of buttons, and I am using a jQuery function called `bgAddRemoveClass` to add and remove the class `active-button` from those buttons when they are clicked.

The problem is both sets of buttons change at the same time, but I need to only change `button-set-1` or `button-set-2`. Not both at the same time.

Here is my broken code:

```js
/* Add and remove a class */
function bgAddRemoveClass(elem1, elem2, theClassNoDot) {

  jQuery(elem1).click(function() {
    jQuery(elem1).addClass(theClassNoDot);
    jQuery(elem2).removeClass(theClassNoDot);
  });
  jQuery(elem2).click(function() {
    jQuery(elem2).addClass(theClassNoDot);
    jQuery(elem1).removeClass(theClassNoDot);
  });

}

/* Invoke the function for button-set-1 */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  bgAddRemoveClass('.sm-btn-left', '.sm-btn-right', 'active-button');
});
```

```css
.sm-btn-left {
  color: red;
}

.sm-btn-right {
  color: blue;
}

.active-button {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.button-set-2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="button-set-1">
  <div class="sm-btn-left flag-map-btns map_btn active-button">
    Map
  </div>
  <div class="sm-btn-right flag-map-btns flags_btn">
    List
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button-set-2">
  <div class="sm-btn-left flag-map-btns map_btn active-button">
    Map
  </div>
  <div class="sm-btn-right flag-map-btns flags_btn">
    List
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried targeting just `button-set-1` like this, but it breaks the functionality completely:

```
/* Invoke the function for button-set-1 */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.button-set-1').bgAddRemoveClass('.sm-btn-left', '.sm-btn-right', 'active-button');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the clicked element's parent in a variable and use it in your selection.

```js
/* Add and remove a class */
function bgAddRemoveClass(elem1, elem2, theClassNoDot) {

  jQuery(elem1).click(function() {
    var parent = jQuery(this).parent();
    
    jQuery(elem1, parent).addClass(theClassNoDot);
    jQuery(elem2, parent).removeClass(theClassNoDot);
  });
  jQuery(elem2).click(function() {
    var parent = jQuery(this).parent();
    
    jQuery(elem2, parent).addClass(theClassNoDot);
    jQuery(elem1, parent).removeClass(theClassNoDot);
  });

}

/* Invoke the function for button-set-1 */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  bgAddRemoveClass('.sm-btn-left', '.sm-btn-right', 'active-button');
});
```

```css
.sm-btn-left {
  color: red;
}

.sm-btn-right {
  color: blue;
}

.active-button {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.button-set-2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="button-set-1">
  <div class="sm-btn-left flag-map-btns map_btn active-button">
    Map
  </div>
  <div class="sm-btn-right flag-map-btns flags_btn">
    List
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button-set-2">
  <div class="sm-btn-left flag-map-btns map_btn active-button">
    Map
  </div>
  <div class="sm-btn-right flag-map-btns flags_btn">
    List
  </div>
</div>
```